# dotcloud django mongo 502

Tags: django, mongodb, dotcloud

I got a django app from https://github.com/jpetazzo/django-and-mongodb-on-dotcloud

but the app is gets a 502 - application not responding error.

while deploying the app, the waitfordb and manage throws authentication error.
I sshed and ran these scripts individually all ran fine, but still the server throws 502 error.

Can someone give some pointers. I need to set up a django based app using mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a recent change (bug fix) to the python service's master `nginx.conf` file. Originally it declared a nginx location block like this.

```
location /static { root /home/dotcloud/data ; }
```

which broke things, so it was changed to this.

```
location /static/ { root /home/dotcloud/data ; }
```

When this happend anyone who has declared their own `/static/` location block in their own `nginx.conf` file will result in an nginx error, and it won't start. You can confirm this is your problem by sshing into your service.

```
dotcloud ssh <application.service>
```

And then looking at your nginx log files in `/var/log/nginx/`.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove your `/static/` location block from your `nginx.conf` file and then repush your application.

The repo you are referring to above, hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: thanks a lot for the info. I got the sample app up and running.